# jQuery "after-click" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a list of links that open in an iframe, like:

```
<ul id="frameTrigger">
    <li><a target="iframe1" href="aaa.html"><img src="aaa.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a target="iframe1" href="bbb.html"><img src="bbb.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a target="iframe1" href="ccc.html"><img src="ccc.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to update another div *after* the link is clicked. Specifically, I need to call a function that checks the frame's `src` attribute and update the div. If I do a:

```
$("#frameTrigger a").click(function() {
    var iframe = $("iframe[name=iframe1]").get(0);
    console.log(iframe.contentWindow.location.href);
    // the problem here is that that the iframe.window.location will
    // change AFTER this function returns
});
```

I do not get what is expected.

Comment: If the links move to a different domain name than yours, you won't be able to pull the SRC.

Comment: `$("#frameTrigger")` you are missing # ... just in case

Comment: @Khez: you are right, I now see the problem and therefore have to revise the question.

Comment: @3nigma: I've fixed the typo, but now there is another problem, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing you get the old value instead of the new one?  You may want to wrap your function in a `setTimeout` of 1ms to allow the update to go through.

Comment: In this particular case a longer timeout (500ms) was needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#frameTrigger a").click(function(){
    console.log( $(this).attr("href") );
});
```

You need the first selector to work on clicks for the links.  Also, I think you had the syntax for console.log incorrect (though I have never used it).  I changed it so when you click on a link it logs the href attribute of the link.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with the entire click functionality completing when calling the click via jQuery .click() - I know it's not ideal, but - perhaps you should just have jQuery explicitly complete the sequence that should be executed when clicked. Something like:

```
$("#someElement").bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $($("#frameTrigger a:eq(1)").attr('target')).attr('src', $("#frameTrigger a:eq(1)").attr('href'));
});
```